# How to sequentially call the Getx controllers

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx, stream-builder

My Task is :

- I have an `list of orders` in firebase in `users` collection ,
- I want to get information of those orders which is in `orders` collection,
- And moment a list of order is updated in the firebase `users` collection.
- The orders list should be automatically updated to get the latest information from the `orders` collection.

But for that i have to wait until list of orders is fetched from the `users` collection and only then i can query from `orders` collection about those orders..
I am stuck here,

And i want to actually understand Getx's bindStream , ever(), and observable variables,and Obx() is used in widget , But what if it is normal variable and i want to listen to it's changes ,how to do that, because Obx() can be only used while you use Widget

So far my code:

**controllers.dart**

```
UtilityController utilityController = UtilityController.instance;
CartController cartController = CartController.instance;
OrderController orderController = OrderController.instance;
```

**UserModel.dart**

```
class UserModel {
  String? uid;
  String? email;
  String? name;
  bool? isAdmin;
  String? password;
  List<CartItemModel>? cart;
  String? token;
  List<String>? orders;

  UserModel({this.uid, this.email, this.name, this.isAdmin, this.password, this.cart, this.token, this.orders});

 
  UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    uid = snapshot.id;
    name = snapshot['name'];
    token = snapshot['token'];
    cart = _convertCartItems(snapshot['cart'] ?? []);
    orders = new List<String>.from(snapshot['orders']);
  }

  List<CartItemModel> _convertCartItems(List cartFomDb) {
    List<CartItemModel> _result = [];
    if (cartFomDb.length > 0) {
      cartFomDb.forEach((element) {
        _result.add(CartItemModel.fromMap(element));
      });
    }
    return _result;
  }
}
```

**UtilityController.dart**

```
class UtilityController extends GetxController {
  static UtilityController instance = Get.find();
  Rx<UserModel> userModel = UserModel().obs;

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    getUserType();
    userModel.bindStream(listenToUser());
  }

  Stream<UserModel> listenToUser() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(snapshot));
  }
```

**OrderController.dart**

```
class OrderController extends GetxController {
  static OrderController instance = Get.find();
  RxList<OrderModel> orders = RxList<OrderModel>([]);

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    orders.bindStream(getAllOrders());
    ever(utilityController.userModel, function); --> I am using this , but i know this is not the correct way
  }

  function(UserModel userModel) {
    getAllOrders();
  }

  Stream<List<OrderModel>> getAllOrders() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("orders")
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: utilityController.userModel.value.orders)
        .snapshots()
        .map((query) => query.docs.map((item) => OrderModel.fromMap(item.data(), item.id)).toList());
  }
}
```

The `utilityController.userModel.value.orders` is null !!! it's not yet loaded, so all the orders are fetched :(
And even if the orders are changed... But new orders are not fetched from the `orders` collection

How to get over this?

Comment: why need obx? just add obs if you want variable observable and use obx to show or change widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The best approach is to use the `worker functions` provided by getx controller like:

- [ever](https://pub.dev/documentation/get_rx/latest/get_rx/ever.html) -  is called every time the Rx variable emits a new value.
- [everAll](https://pub.dev/documentation/get_rx/latest/get_rx/everAll.html) - Much like `ever` , but it takes a `List` of *Rx* values Called every time its variable is changed. That's it.
- [once](https://pub.dev/documentation/get_rx/latest/get_rx/once.html) - is called only the first time the variable has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using like this.

```
class OrderController extends GetxController {
  static OrderController instance = Get.find();
  final isLoading = true.obs;
  final isDone = false.obs;
  var orders = OrderModel([]).obs;

@override
  void onInit() async {
    await listenForOrders();
    super.onInit();
  }
 
Future listenForOrders() async {
    isLoading.value = true;
    isDone.value = false;
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> _userOrders;
    _userOrders = getAllOrders();
    _userOrders.listen((QuerySnapshot query) {
      if (query.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        query.docs.forEach((element) {
          orders.addIf(!orders.contains(element), OrderModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(element));
        });
      } else {
        isDone.value = true;
      }
      isLoading.value = false;
    });
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getAllOrders() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("orders")
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: utilityController.userModel.value.orders)
        .snapshots();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer , but it isn't working. And  if you add details , it would be great. to understand